# Error with SpyObj how to reassign the value of spy

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spyon

I'm fairly new to Jasmine so excuse my silly question.

I'm trying to override the value of the spy only for one `it` block and I'm hitting issues.

I'm seeing `ERROR: <spyOn> : ActionsEnabled has already been spied upon` error. How do i fix this?

Here is my code:

```
describe('Side Pane', () => {
  const state = cleanState<{
    component: Component,
    store: Store<{}>,
  }>(() => {
    spyOn(Flags, 'ActionsEnabled').and.returnValue(true);

    setupHybridModule({
      imports:
          [ActionsModule],
      providers: []
    });

    const store = get(Store);

    return {component: bootstrap(Actions), store};
  }, beforeEach);


  it('expects component to be hidden by default', () => {
    // I want to disable the flag and test
    spyOn(Flags, 'ActionsEnabled').and.returnValue(false); // ERROR: <spyOn> : ActionsEnabled has already been spied upon
    expect(hasEl('.actions-header')).toBeFalse();
  });
```

I'd appreciate some insights on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the quirks of Jasmine where if something has been spied on, it cannot be spied upon again. To fix this issue, you can assign the `spyOn` to a "global" variable within the describe block and then use this "global" variable to change the value.

Follow comments with !!:

```
describe('Side Pane', () => {
  // !! Declare the actionsEnabledSpy that will be a spy later on.
  let actionsEnabledSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  const state = cleanState<{
    component: Component,
    store: Store<{}>,
  }>(() => {
    // !! Assign the spyOn to the actionsEnabledSpy
    actionsEnabledSpy = spyOn(Flags, 'ActionsEnabled').and.returnValue(true);

    setupHybridModule({
      imports:
          [ActionsModule],
      providers: []
    });

    const store = get(Store);

    return {component: bootstrap(Actions), store};
  }, beforeEach);


  it('expects component to be hidden by default', () => {
    // I want to disable the flag and test
    // !! Over here, use the actionsEnabledSpy to change the value
    actionsEnabledSpy.and.returnValue(false);
    // !! You can also get other methods on actionsEnabledSpy like reset() to reset the spy (clear out all the times it was called).
    expect(hasEl('.actions-header')).toBeFalse();
  });
```

Comment: For some reason the `it` test case fails

`Error: Expected true to be false.`

Comment: I'd appreciate some help! @AliF50

Comment: You most likely need a `fixture.detectChanges()` between the `actionsEnabledSpy.and.returnValue(false);` and `expect(...`. Most likely the component TypeScript got updated but the view needs a change detection cycle to get updated.